# Room @Embedded vs One on One Relationship

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

While working on my project, i've encounter a case on having specific data class belong to entity

```
data class Profile(
   val profileImage: String,
   val backgroundImage: String
)

@Entity
data class User(
  val id: Int,
  val email: String,
  val name: String,

  @Embedded
  val profile: Profile
)
```

Lets use this as example. In this case, i can also use one on one relationship in `Room`. And make it looks like this:

```
@Entity
data class Profile(
   val id: Int,
   val userId: Int
   val profileImage: String,
   val backgroundImage: String
)

data class UserWithProfile(
  @Embedded
  val user: User

   @Relation(
        parentColumn = "id",
        entityColumn = "userId",
    )
    val profile: Profile
)
```

But, what is the advantage of One on One relationship with separate table instead of just embedding? I've tried to find any resource about this but didn't get anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But, what is the advantage of One on One relationship with separate table instead of just embedding?

**IF** the data (in your case the profile) is repeated (say there are a small finite number of images to pick from) then the advantage is a saving in space by using a/the related 2nd table. However, this is then NOT a 1-1 relationship but a 1(image)-many(profiles that reference an image) relationship. In short the 1-many meets what is termed as [normalisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) of which not repeating data is an aspect(rule/constraint).

**IF** the data is not repeated and thus truly a 1-1 relationship then a 2nd table is likely of little benefit and could be a detrimental as the schema is larger and more space may need to be managed.

- each table has to utilise at least 1 page (4k by default), and
- the schema is a little larger, and
- for there must be an index associated with the table which has to be maintained (when inserting and deleting rows and potentially also when updating (if the primary key is changed)).

  - however, indexes can be highly beneficial when accessing the stored data.

As such, you should consider into which of the two conditions above the data actually falls to decide what is likely the best approach.

Of course there is a third option to not Embed but just include the object (Profile) as a single column e.g.

```
@Entity
data class User(
  @PrimaryKey
  val id: Int,
  val email: String,
  val name: String,
  val profile: Profile
)
```

However, this would then require two `TypeConverter`'s to convert the  Profile object into a single value that can be stored into an SQLite column e.g. a JSON representation.

- one function to convert from the object (Profile) to the value to be stored.
- another function to convert the stored data into the object (Profile) when extracting data from the database.

Although very frequently the choice made by many, this approach has disadvantages:-

- obviously you need the two `TypeConverter`s and annotations to utilise the `TypeConverter`s.
- the value derived by the TypeConverter that is to be stored will have to include additional data that allows the construction of the resultant data (bloat). So this increases the size of the stored data.
- due to the bloat and embedded values all being a single value finding values can be difficult.
- see https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/referencing-data

> Lets use this as example.....

There is NOTHING stopping a **User** being referenced/mapped/related to many Profiles, so really this is a 1(Profile)-Many(Users) even though it does support a 1-1 relationship.

e.g. You could create/store:-

```
Profile(1,1,'Image1','BImageA')
Profile(2,1,'Image3','BImageB') /* i.e. User 1 */
```

**However**, your example appears to be the wrong way around. To properly replicate your **User** having a single **Profile** (which was originally `@Embedded`) then you would use:-

```
@Entity
data class Profile(
   @PrimaryKey
   val id: Int,
   val profileImage: String,
   val backgroundImage: String
)
```

- NOTE the `UserId` field has been removed.

Along with:-

```
@Entity
data class User(
  @PrimaryKey
  val id: Int,
  val email: String,
  val name: String,
  val profileId: Int
)
```

- Note the replacement of the `@Embedded` Profile with the **profileId** field i.e. the **1** Profile related to the **User**.

And :-

```
data class UserWithProfile(
  @Embedded
  val user: User

   @Relation(
        parentColumn = "id",
        entityColumn = "profileId",
    )
    val profile: Profile
)
```

- again still 1-M as multiple users could reference/relate to/map to the same Profile.

Comment: I see the point now, thank you so much for giving great explanation alongside with code samples. Really appreciate your help, have a great day sir